# what does math symbol [ x ]+ mean?

Tags: notation, education

I saw a math symbol looks like this, anyone know what does it stands for?
$$-V^t + G[D^T]^+$$

Comment: Where does this come up? You'll need to give much more context - otherwise this could mean almost anything

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. We might be able to help if you [edit] the question to show us more context - the paragraph containing this formula, and, perhaps, the earlier definition of $G$. Please use mathjax rather than an image: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean to have a lone plus sign in the exponent/superscript (Modified Weiszfeld algorithm)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043399/what-does-it-mean-to-have-a-lone-plus-sign-in-the-exponent-superscript-modified)

Comment: Yes that pretty much answered my question! Thanks! I marked it as duplicated.