# Functions and exponents

Tags: functions, exponential-function, exponentiation

I am a computer science student. I do not know much about the functions in maths. What does it mean to have a plus sign as exponent. 
[plese see equation number 23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjZ0y.png)

I unable to understand it.

Comment: This should be explained somewhere in this book/the lecture notes. I don't know the notation and it it's probably not standard, so try to find an explanation in the manuscript. Maybe there's a glossary of notations and symbols?

Comment: It's not an exponent, probably this notation is introduced earlier in the text.

Comment: It is available at http://libgen.bban.top/ireader/48669219. These kind of equations are shown in section 3.1. Nowhere, I found the explanation. Kindly, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the + sign means the expression can't be negative. If it's negative the + sign makes the expresssion 0.

My answer is based on this:

[What does it mean to have a lone plus sign in the exponent/superscript (Modified Weiszfeld algorithm)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043399/what-does-it-mean-to-have-a-lone-plus-sign-in-the-exponent-superscript-modified)